# Как правильно сделать поворот объекта в сторону другого?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Посмотрел несколько решений этого вопроса, но постоянно происходит эта проблема. Текст отзеркаливается, и не понятно, что написано. Использовал LookAT, с ним такая же проблема. Сейчас такой код на тексте.

```
private Transform pers;
public float speed = 5f;

void Update()
{
    Vector3 direction = pers.transform.position - transform.position;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);                                                                        
}
void Start()
{
    pers = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("cam").FirstOrDefault()?.GetComponent<Transform>();    
}
```

а вот результат, написано яблоко, а показывается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидно что текст(насколько я понимаю текст или капсулу с текстом нужно поворачивать к камере) смотрит в обратную сторону от камеры. Попробуйте обратить вектор направления:

```cs
Vector3 direction = transform.position - pers.transform.position; // вместо pers.transform.position - transform.position
```

Или так:

```cs
Vector3 direction = pers.transform.position - transform.position;
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(-direction);
```